# C++ Get a specified part from a char

Tags: c++, char

I read a line from a text file, where in the end of the line there are numbers (format: "some text.001"), and I would like to get the number after the 0 or 0s. So if it's 001, then 1, if it's 010, then it's 10.
What I got now:

```
fgets(strLine, 100, m_FileStream);
// Here I need to cut the numbers into myNum
int num = atoi(&myNum);
```

I tried with strrchr to get the position of the ".", but don't know what's next. Maybe I need strtok, but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: This looks more like `C` than `C++`. In general, use `cin` and `std::string` in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the position of the `.` you can advance by one `char` and use `atoi()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[20] = "some text.010";
    char* period_ptr = strrchr(buf, '.');
    if (period_ptr)
    {
        printf("%d\n", atoi(++period_ptr));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a C solution, not C++, but should work:

```
const char *filename = "some text.001";
char *p = strrchr(filename, '.');
if (p != NULL)
{
    int num = atoi(p+1);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
else
{
    // No extension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
fgets(..);
int iPos = strLine.find_last_of('0');
string strNum = strLine.substr(iPos, strLine.length()-iPos);
int num = ...
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

Haven't tested it though.

Comment: And if the file extension doesn't start with '0'?

Comment: That's why I added the link: find_last_pos returns npos if 0 is not found. You can then check like if(iPos != std::npos)... I would expect a tiny little bit of self-motivation/investigation. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The function `strtol()` (or a variant) is your friend for number conversion - prefer it to `atoi()` as you've got more control over conversion and error detection. For a C++ approach, you could use STL:

```
string s = "some text.001";
size_t p = s.find_last_of('.');
cout << (( p != string::npos ) ? strtol( s.substr(p+1).c_str(), NULL, 0 ) : -1) << endl;
```

**Output:**

1